# Constantly message "is waiting for the debugger on port 8100" Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When you are working with the option "Attach debugger to Android process" and ends abruptly any process, you will have constantly
the message "is waiting for the debugger on port 8100" doing Run or Debug. You can solve the issues rebooting (turn off/on) your device.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution to the problem?

Comment: Turn off/on the device is the immediate solution but I think that with the last Android Studio this issue should not be happen.